# Replace every word in a document based on a defined pattern

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a file with thousands of document, and i want to read every documents and replace each word in this document like a pattern (Key,Value) at first all values are zero(0),
docs file :

```
 Problems installing software weak tech support.
 great idea executed perfect.
 A perfect solution for anyone who listens to the radio.
    ...
```

and i have a score_file contains many words: e.g.

```
idea 1
software 1
weak 1
who 1
perfect 1
price -1
...
```

output like this pattern:

```
(Problems,0) (installing,1) (software,1) (develop,2) (weak,1) (tech,1) (support,0).
(great,1) (idea,1) (executed,2) (perfect,1).
(perfect,1) (solution,1) (for,0) (anyone,1) (who,1) (listens,1) (to,0) (the,0) (radio,0).
```

if a word of document occur in this score_file then value of `(left word , this word , right word)` in document Adding with 1 or -1 related to word's score.

i've tried :

```
  val Words_file = sc.textFile("score_file.txt")
  val  Words_List = sc.broadcast(Words_file.map({ (line) =>
      val Array(a,b) = line.split(" ").map(_.trim)(a,b.toInt)}).collect().toMap)
  val Docs_file = sc.textFile("docs_file.txt")
  val tokens = Docs_file.map(line => (line.split(" ").map(word => Words_List.value.getOrElse(word, 0)).reduce(_ + _), line.split(" ").filter(Words_List.value.contains(_) == false).mkString(" ")))
  val out_Docs = tokens.map(s => if (s._2.length > 3) {s._1 + "," + s._2})
```

[image]

But it scored every document not its words, how can i generate my favorite output?

Comment: Your sample data/output does not make sense. Can you clarify a little better please

Comment: for every word in a document , replace this word by a key and value (score) then this value can be increased if this word (key) or neighbor words in Words_list

Comment: Sorry, still doesnt make sense to me...can you walk us through a concrete example? Like, why is Problems 0, but develop is 2 (which doesnt even exist in either of the lists....)

Comment: Do the additions/subtractions ONLY happen to the adjacent words, or does the word itself also get the score? If so, then isn't your sample buggy? software should have a 2 as it gets its own 1 and weak's 1

Answer (score 0):

It is kinda hard to read you code, you seem to use a weird mix of CamelCase with underscores with vals sometimes starting with uppercase and sometimes not.

I'm not sure I completely got the question, but to get an output where each word in a given line is replaced by itself and the number coming from the other file, this might work:

```
val sc = new SparkContext()
val wordsFile = sc.textFile("words_file.txt")
val words = sc.broadcast(wordsFile.map( line => {
  val Array(a, b) = line.split(" ").map(_.trim)
  (a,b.toInt)
}).collect().toMap)

val docs = sc.textFile("docs_file.txt")
val tokens = docs.map(line => {
  line.split(" ")
    .map(token => s"(${token}, ${words.value.getOrElse(token, 0)})")
    .mkString(" ")
})
```

`tokens` ends up being just an RDD[String] as the input, preserving lines (documents). I reformatted the code a bit to make it more readable.

Comment: thank you @DanielL, there is some problem with your code, it generates :(Problems, 0) (installing, 0) (software, 1) (weak, 1) (tech, 0) (support., 0) , and it doesn't consider left and right words , also it doesn't consider score that there is in Score_file

Comment: Yeah, as I mentioned, not sure what you meant by that piece. "if a word of document occur in this score_file then value of (left word , this word , right word) in document Adding with 1 or -1 related to word's score.". Maybe if you put an example of that? I tried to go as far as I could ;-)

Comment: I see. Ok, I'm out of town till monday and don't my laptop with me, but here is the gist: Forget about Spark for a second. 1.- Build a function that converts a line to a List[(String, Int)] much as above but not going back to String just yet. 2.- Then on the same method traverse the list all over again, adding the value of the current list cell to the next and previous list cell. 3.- Return from you method `list.mkString(" "). 4.- Simply use your method from spark by doing `docs.map(myFunc)`. In general, if you see your Spark code getting to complex, encapsulation on functions is a good idea.